# Create search field in Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am creating an application with a table view, which has a large amount of data in it. Because of this, it is necessary for me to use a search field.

Does anyone have any idea how to create a search-option in a tableview?

Comment: You should tag your programming language too. For my answer, I just assumed you are using Objective - C...

Comment: search in array and add filtered objects in another array show result in tableview. search on google for it you will find one.

Comment: Here is an official example from apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: yes friend I am using objective C in Iphone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the UISearchBar property, declare it using

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
```

and add it to your UIViewController's view as a subview.

After that, use the searchbar delegate methods in your view controller:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Check out [this](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=228) tutorial to get a hang of the search bar and its delegates!

EDIT: This method isn't about using a searchbar in tableview itself, but above it. That means you have to put tableView as a subview of a UIViewController, and the searchBar as a subview of the same UIViewController as well!

Comment: Thank you my friend.Its really awesome.I also found 1 doc for that it is as same as yours..its Link is http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html.